# Cannot see "font" resource type in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, fonts, android-8.0-oreo

I was going through the new Android O features, and one of the new thing is now app can add fonts directly into `res` folder. As per the android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/working-with-fonts.html) for working with fonts, one of the 1st step is to create a new resource type named "font" using Right-click the res folder and go to New > Android resource directory.

But I could not see "font" option available for resource type in the drop down in android studio.

Below is the image attached.
[image]

I am not able to see "font" option in the drop down, and hence I am unable to create font android resource directory.

My Android studio details:

**Android Studio 2.3
Build #AI-162.3764568, built on February 24, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b06 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o**

Comment: "Only Android Studio 2.4 includes support for all the new developer features available with Android O." - https://developer.android.com/preview/migration.html#bfa

Comment: @MikeM. ok, thanks! I am updating Android studio to 2.4 now from Canary channel. Will update my answer if I could see the font resource type in AS-2.4

Comment: Anyone got any workaround now? Without updating AS out of stable version

Comment: I am not able to preview the ttf file in fonts folder in android studio

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As said by Mike in comments, currently Android Studio 2.4 includes support for all the new developer features available with Android O.

I used Android Studio 2.4 Preview from Canary Channel, & I could see the option for "font" when choosing the Android resource directory.

Below is the image for the same.

[image]

Comment: Do you know why it is not visible in Android Studio 3.0 Beta 4

Comment: Do I need to set a specific `minSdkVersion`?  I have Android Studio 3.0 and still can not see `font` type. `compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.foo.bar"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26`

Answer (score 33):

One thing I noticed is that the drop down is actually scrollable but because the scrollbar is quite dark, others might not notice it. I can't find "font" at first until I scrolled it downwards.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update Android studio to 3.0 beta 2 to use all latest features of font family

Answer (score 1):

In case you're wondering how to use these new fonts programmatically (which took me some time to figure out), refer to [this tutorial from SEGUN](https://segunfamisa.com/posts/custom-fonts-with-android-support-library). He teaches the following:

**Java:**

```
Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.app_font);
fontText.setTypeface(typeface);
```

**Kotlin**:

```
val myCustomFont : Typeface? = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.my_font)
fontText.typeface = myCustomFont
```

**Note:** you'll need to have the `.ttf` font downloaded in your project to do so - not just the `.xml` for the downloadable font.

Comment: Worked for me. My fonts are under res/font and I use Android Studio 3.1 Canary 3

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: create new folder name it 'assets' under app/src/main manually.

Step 2: create 'fonts' name folder inside assets folder.

Step 3: put your .ttf files under fonts folder.

then check your studio project structure.

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking about. They're trying to use the new font _resources_ available in Android O.

Comment: As @MikeM. i am not looking for how to use custom font. i am trying out the new Android O way of adding a font