# Getting error "file name must end with .xml" while using the "android:fontFamily" of Android O?

Tags: android, layout, fonts, android-resources, android-8.0-oreo

Android O introduces a new feature, Fonts in XML, which lets you use fonts as resources. And I am creating the `font` folder in resource file as it provided by [Android developer](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/working-with-fonts.html), but the problem is that I am getting error that `file name must end with .xml` while using the `font` folder which is provided in Android O release.

Please check the below  layout for it.

```
 <TextView
   android:id="@+id/txtMsgCount"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="16dp"
   android:background="@drawable/msg_count"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:text="123"
   android:fontFamily="@font/Montserrat_Regular" ////IT IS MY FONT STYLE
   android:textColor="@android:color/white"
   android:textSize="10sp" />
```

And please check the `font` folder which I have created in `res` with `Montserrat_Regular.otf` file

[image: My font folder with font style]

I am getting the following error while using the above, which are as follows:

[image: Error getting]

I have searched about it but did not get expected result, please check:

[1. First Link](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/working-with-fonts.html)
[2. Second Link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-working-with-custom-fonts-in-android-o--cms-28625)
[3. Third Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128331/how-to-change-fontfamily-of-textview-in-android)
[4. Forth Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691530/valid-values-for-androidfontfamily-and-what-they-map-to)

And the  `Font resource file` is not creating as I am clicking the `Right-click the font folder and go to New > Font resource file`. But not getting the option of the `Font resource file`, please check below:

[image]

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: where is your font family xml

Comment: I am using 2.3.3 @CommonsWare

Comment: Yes i have read about it.It does not allow me to create the font-family in font folder

Comment: @AkhileshPatil It does not provide me option to create the font-family on the font folder

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43152907/cannot-see-font-resource-type-in-android-studio

Comment: @MikeM. My problem is that i am not able to create the ` Font resource file` when i right click on the `font` folder

Comment: Yeah, you said you're using Android Studio version 2.3.3. You need 2.4, at least.

Comment: It is not updated..I have check on updater..It says u have latest version

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html, https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/

Comment: Did you find any way to do this?

Comment: @MohitGoel U need to update your `Andoid studio ` `3. 0` to  get this..Currently which android studio  version are u using?

Comment: I know that. but I am working on a live project. So I cant take risk of using beta version.

Comment: Do i need to use old way?

Comment: Till than YES..It will no harm to u. :)

Comment: I am trying to do the same but it is giving me following error:                 
Error:(417) Attribute "font" already defined with incompatible format.

Comment: I am also using maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

Comment: @MohitGoel U need to delete the font folder , if u are using the traditional way..And put the file inside the `assest` folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152741/discussion-between-mohit-goel-and-ravindra-kushwaha).

Comment: Sorry i am busy now..Ping u as become free

Comment: Thanks for ur help. its done.

Comment: @MohitGoel Good to hear dost..Keep happy coding :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Font resources are not fully supported by the Android Studio 2.3.3 build chain. Full support comes with Android Studio 3.0+ and its associated Android Plugin for Gradle version. At that point, you will be able to create a `font/` resource directory that goes alongside `layout/`, `menu/`, etc.

IOW, hold off on this until you are ready to upgrade to Android Studio 3.0.

Comment: Apparently "canary" has been renamed to "preview" and the Android studio build has been relabeled to "beta": http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest

Comment: Means there is no other way on 2.3.3..I am also using the `kotlin` whose version `3.0 Beta `..I think it will run on that...But my problem is not resolved  because i need to do work on `Andorid `..Thanks for input..:)

Comment: @M66B: They must have bumped Android Studio 3.0 up to Beta 1 while I was asleep. Last I knew, they were on Canary 9 or so.

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha: "Means there is no other way on 2.3.3" -- you're welcome to try the 3.0 beta version of the Plugin with AS 2.3.3, but I strongly suspect that it will not work.

Comment: @CommonsWare it looks more structural, since the "canary" page refers to a "preview" page now. This was changed yesterday (CET) or earlier. Although, on the other hand this page suggests otherwise: https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html

Comment: @CommonsWare Just checked, using the 3.0.0-beta1 version of the Gradle plugin does not work with AS 2.3.3. Gradle sync fails with `Error:This Gradle plugin requires Studio 3.0 minimum`.

Answer (score 4):

I've lost an hour on this error, using AS 3.0 beta2, Gradle 4.x and the correct build-tools.

Turned out I had a copy of the fonts in a folder called "fonts". This folder doesn't show up in the Android project view. And reading the error I didn't catch the 's'. Just a small reminder for you readers!

Comment: Hi there. A number of folks in our community sometimes say that every time they see gendered assumptions about software engineers, they worry about people feeling excluded. I wonder, could you try to avoid adding male-oriented greetings and pronouns in your posts, so as to make for a more welcoming environment? Thank you.

Comment: Indeed, that was my case as well. I wonder why it was duplicated.

Comment: In my case, it was a wrongly named values directory. So just scan your structure for a bad name.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem and while searching for an answer, I came here on this thread.
I've found a solution from [deverloper.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html).

> 1. Right click 'res' folder in Android Studio
> 2. Choose 'new' > 'Android resource directory'
> 3. Name it 'font'
> 4. Inhere you should place your font (.ttf) files **WITH ONLY** a-z 0-9 and _ characters.
> 5. Set your font *(mine is called 'alegreyaregular.ttf')* this way:

```
Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.alegreyaregular);
TextView textView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Comment: Hey!! Look at that. I was already doing what all the other answers were suggesting but it still was not working. This is the only thing that worked for.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly same error ***file name must end with .xml*** I used these settings and problem magically resolved.

**Use these setting in Project Level Gradle :**

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.company.app"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
...
}
```

**Use these setting in Application Level Gradle :**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

**Android Stidio :**

```
Android studio version 3.0.1.
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I had faced same problem!!
Just update your build.gradle file to resolve above issue.

### classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

compileSdkVersion 26

### buildToolsVersion '26.0.3'

Update your AndroidStudio to latest vetsion.

Enjoy your day.

Answer (score 1):

**Android Studio 2.4** includes support for all the new developer features available with **Android O** you need to update studio

And create **XML file**

1) Right-click the font folder and go to New > Font resource file. The New Resource File window appears.

2) Enter the file name, and then click OK. The new font resource XML opens in the editor.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <font
    android:fontStyle="normal"
    android:fontWeight="400"
    android:font="@font/Montserrat_Regular.otf" />

</font-family>
```

Comment: I am not able to create `Creating a font family` on my `font` folder.It does not provide me option..I know this way..But when i right optiion on `font` than it  does not provide me ` Font resource file`

Comment: I have just checked for update , it does not allow me to update my android studio from `2.3.3 to 2.4`..It say u have updated version

Comment: Thanks for input ..Problem is not resolved :(..+1 for effort

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of generic issue and I faced this one with error message

main\res\lib\poi-3.12-android-a.jar: Error: The file name must end with .xml

I had placed this jar file inside resource folder(res), I removed this jar file and folder it get resolved. 
Avoid any unwanted files/folder inside res directory.