# The font file name must end with .xml

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fonts

Please click here to view the [FontError Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z93IM.png)

Please, what might be the cause?

Comment: rename the folder font in fonts (or something else)

Comment: what version of android studio are you using??

Comment: @Rishabh pls am using android 3.6.1

Comment: @Blackbelt pls can you come back? I don't really get you.

Comment: did you put the ttf files in res/font as well?

Comment: @Blackbelt yes please.

Comment: delete them from res/font then

Comment: Okay.. thanks very much problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think  you have copy of font file in this address:

```
app/src/main/res/fonts/..
```

and if you sure that, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45633502/getting-error-file-name-must-end-with-xml-while-using-the-androidfontfamily)

Comment: I just deleted it buh still problem exist

Comment: check the link maybe this problem is for android studio version

Comment: pls i think I've already  read that post but still can not solve the problem. And pls I'm using android version 3.6.1

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved!**
There was another fonts folder hidden inside the res/ but it but wasn't showing in android project files. And the program still holds this reference file I deleted.

> This is "wizard-error"
> . Lol

**How I solved it**

1. I went to my project folder on my desktop
2. \app\src\main\res\font
3. Right clicked on it and deleted it.

invalidate and restart the android studio.

Thanks to my helpers.